# Possible to run command on remote Windows from Airflow on linux machine

Tags: airflow

I have an ETL process that currently brings data from a remote DB into HDFS and then uses `bcp` from the `mssql-tools` package to transfer data as TSVs from the linux machines into a Windows MSSQL DB. I would like to set up this process using Airflow on another linux server. To do this, I plan to mount the HDFS folder via NFS onto the Windows machine and run an SSIS package to transfer the data into the MSSQL DB. Is there a way/operator to run commands on a remote Windows machine from Airflow? Eg.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /FILE "c:\users\me\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\etl_flatfiles\Integration Services Project1\Package.dtsx" /DECRYPT "password"
```

Comment: For remote command execution, Airflow provides [`SSHOperator`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/ssh_operator.py) that internally uses [`SSHHook`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/hooks/ssh_hook.py); and the convention is to define settings (user credentials / key-file etc) in an [`SSH` `Connection`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/connection.py#L89) (webUI)